# Data manipulatuon of xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing a multi-user desktop application in c#. I am using XML file as a database for storing the username and password of new users and i want to a new element in the users.xml file whenever a user signs up. So how can i do it ?? 
Provide me the suitable code by which a new element can be added along with the old elements in the users.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Load your xml document using XDocument.Load() method, then you can traverse the XML nodes using XElements, XAttributes etc. It's fairly easy. 
Read al about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Also if you need more resources, just hit your favourite search engine and look for "Linq to XML"

here is an example

```
    var document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\registrations.xml");

    var peopleElement = document.Root.Elements().First(e => e.Name.LocalName == "people");

    peopleElement.Add(new XElement("person", 
                new XAttribute("name", firstName),
                new XAttribute("surname", lastName),
                new XAttribute("date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
            )
        );
    document.Save(@"C:\temp\registrations.xlm");
```

Comment: I want to add new elements in a xml file for storing new user's information such as username and password

Comment: Very simple. You can very easilly locate the xml element that contains your users, and then just add another element to it using Add(new XElement()) (where the XElement contains attributes or values depending on how you want your xml to look). It is a very powerful way of working with XML. But it has a small learning curve, but it's not very difficult. If you give it one hour, you'll be a jedi :)

Comment: Let me explain you the whole situation. I have a multi user application in which i have created a sign up form. Now whenever the user enters the details and clicks on signup button a new element should be created in the users.xml file. Also the old elements should not be deleted.

Comment: Also i dont want to use linq in the application as i am developing it for windows xp.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to clarify. XP is inconsequential to this. This is C# and it will compile. Don't forget to tag the answer if it solves your problem :)